# How to filter locations in csv file by Python or Tableau prep?

Tags: python, pandas, tableau-api, data-cleaning, preprocessor

I have a csv file of 20K Tweets which a column of that is the user's location. the locations are from all regions of the world but only the states of America are important for us. The screenshot of the dataset is the following:
[image]

How can I filter this file to only keep rows that their user's location is a state of America, by Python or Tableau Prep? (remove all rows that their locations are not from USA)

Comment: dataframe.loc[dataframe['name of column'] == 'value which need to filter']

Comment: or you can use  dataframe query as well  dataframe.query('column name' == 'value')

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @qaiser thanks for your response. So should I mention all 50 states with all their possibilities(such as NY, New York, NYC, ...) in your formula? for example: dataframe.loc[dataframe['name of column'] == 'New York, NY,New Jersey, NJ, California, Ca, Arizona, AZ, Maryland, MD, .....'].

Comment: build a set, from online sources of all states in all sorts of forms, it should give you most cases, for 100% or close, you need to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(['Usa','Australia','Asia','Africa','Europe'],columns = ['continent'])


# make a list of word you want to filter 

list_ = ['Asia','Europe','Africa']


# now you can use pandas isin functionality to filter the data that you want

df.loc[df['continent'].isin(list_)]

#op
    continent
2   Asia
3   Africa
4   Europe
```